# Image upload for image processing to fill up related form fields in Django

Tags: javascript, django

I am new to Django. My task is to upload an image and do some image processing on it and fill up some fields based on the results obtained from the image. Then the user would maybe check if the values that get filled in are correct and if they are they will save the whole form with the image and all the other form fields.

So, I am confused about the following. I already have the util functions for the image processing which is in python. How should I obtain the image immediately after the user select the file and do the image processing and receive my data from the processing keeping in mind that this will be happening in the server.

My url for this page is "admin/book/add".

I am not providing any code because I wanted to the general way of how to do something like this in django.

My model includes ->

BookModel:
name, author, year

ImageModel:
Image, Image_thumbnail.

// this will be filled after image processing
Constructs:
x, y, z

Finally, the user will hit the save button and save

I have tried using javascript to send AJAX and send the image only to backend, but this is not working. I face an error "TooManyFieldsSent". I was expecting to send the image to the server and then catch the image in the server and do the image processing and then send the data back.